# xhr.abort(); on cancelBtn event

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I am working on file upload with progress bar and cancel button to abort uploading.
I have my upload.html as below,

```
<div class="row">
   <div id="alert-box">{{ msg }}</div>
   <div id="image-box"></div>
   <div class="col-md-2"><label><b>File :</b></label></div>
   <div class="col-md-2"><input type="file" id="fileupload" name="fileupload"  required multiple></div>
</div><br>
<div class="container">
    <div id="progress-box" class="progress not-visible">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progessbar" >progress</div>
</div>
</div>
    <div id="cancel-box" class="not-visible">
    <button id="cancel-btn" class="btn btn-danger">cancel</button>
</div>
```

and main.js as,

```
const uploadForm = document.getElementById('upload-form')
const input = document.getElementById('fileupload')
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submitBtn')

const alertBox = document.getElementById('alert-box')
const progressBox = document.getElementById('progress-box')
const cancelBox = document.getElementById('cancel-box')
const cancelBtn = document.getElementById('cancel-btn')

const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')

$("#upload-form").submit(function(e){            
            $form = $(this)
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            const media_data = input.files[0];          
            if(media_data != null){
                console.log(media_data);
                progressBox.classList.remove("not-visible");
                cancelBox.classList.remove("not-visible");              
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:'/',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function(){
                },              
                xhr:function(){                    
                    const xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', e=>{
                        if(e.lengthComputable){
                            const percentProgress = (e.loaded/e.total)*100;
                            console.log(percentProgress);
                            progressBox.innerHTML = `<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success" 
                    role="progressbar" style="width: ${percentProgress}%" aria-valuenow="${percentProgress}" aria-valuemin="0" 
                    aria-valuemax="100"></div>`
                        }
                    })          
                    
                    cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', e=>{                        
                        xhr.abort();
                        console.log("Abort event");
                        progressBox.innerHTML="";                       
                        progressBox.classList.add("not-visible");
                        cancelBox.classList.add('not-visible');
                    })              
                    
                    return xhr
                },
                
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log("successfully upload");
                    progressBox.classList.add("not-visible");
                    cancelBox.classList.add("not-visible");
                    uploadForm.reset();
                },
                error: function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
            });
        });
```

I am trying to abort uploading file when some one click on cancel button which appears when file is uploading.

thought it is setting 'not-visible' class to progress bar and cancel button. file still continue to upload.
any thoughts why it is not stop uploading file on xhr.abort() ?

Thanks,
PB.

Comment: You should be preventing the from submitting `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Thank you - Musa. that's stop uploading file. so we don't need xhr.abort()? and just have e.preventDefault(); insted? 
one more thing , it stop uploading file but keep circling on top in browser window- and that's looks like something is still in process to user. how to stop that ?

Comment: When you have a form but want to use ajax instead to upload the data to the server you have to prevent the form from submitting(`e.preventDefault`). Without that you will have the form and ajax both doing the upload. So, no you still have to call `xhr.abort` if you want to have the user manually stop the upload.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification. any thoughts on how to stop circling on window? where favicon symbol display?